# Django, Heroku - [remote rejected] main -> main(pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: python, django

I am reading the [Django for Beginners](https://djangoforbeginners.com/) book to learn deploy django app. From Chapter 3: Pages App, deployment with heroku is taught. However everytime I follow the steps for deployment I get the same error everytime, similar to something shown below with different heroku url.

```
! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/afternoon-anchorage-50413.git'
```